# Error Llamada al método indefinido Base de datos :: prepare ()

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php5

Cordial saludo agradezco por favor su colaboración en el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta, referente a la función prepare ():

Mi código es el siguiente,

1. Mi archivo database.php, tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
    <?php
    class Database{
    private $host;
    private $db;
    private $usuario;
    private $contrasena;
    private $charset;
    private $pdo;
    public function __construct(){
    $this->host='localhost:3306';
    $this->db='grupo4s';
    $this->usuario='root';
    $this->contrasena='';
    $this->charset='utf8mb4';   
    $this->connect();
    }   
    function connect(){
    try{
    $connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db .";usuario=" . $this->usuario .";contrasena=" . $this->contrasena . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
    $options = [ 
         PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
         PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
       ];
    
    $this->pdo= new PDO($connection,$this->usuario, $this->contrasena, $options);
    print_r('Conexion satisfactoriua');
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      print_r('Error connection: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
      echo "Error connection";
    }
    }
    public function getConnection(){
          return $this->pdo;
         }
    }
    ?>
```

El archivo index.php, tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
    <?php
    require_once ('Conexion/database.php');
    session_start();
    
    if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])){
    header("Location: admin.php");  
       }
    if(isset($_GET['cerrar_sesion'])){
          session_unset();
          session_destroy();
    }
    
    if(isset($_SESSION['rol'])){
           switch($_SESSION['rol']) {
             case 1:   
              header('location:admin.php');    
             break;
             case 2:  
              header('location:invitado.php');     
             break;
             default:
            } 
       }
    
    if(isset($_GET['usuario']) && isset($_GET['contrasena'])){
    $usuario=$_GET['usuario'];  //estaba _POST
     $contrasena= $_GET['contrasena']; 
     $db= new Database();
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=usuario AND contrasena=contrasena");
    $query->bind_param(['usuario'=> $usuario,'contrasena'=> $contrasena]);
    $query->execute();
          $query->store_result();
    
    if($query == true){
     $usuario = $row[1];
             $_SESSION['usuario']=$usuario;
            // validar rol
    $rol= $row[6];
    $_SESSION['rol']=$rol;
    switch($_SESSION['rol']) {
              case 1:   
               header('location:admin.php');    
              break;
     
              case 2:  
               header('location:invitado.php');     
              break;
           default:
      
              
            } 
         } else{
    echo"El usuario o contraseña son incorrectos";
         }
          
        }
    
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es">
        <head>
                <style>
    h1 {text-align: center;}   </style>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"> 
            <title>Ingreso</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/config1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <div class="container">
                <div id="contenedor"> 
        <form action="#" methods="post"> <!--ojo recomiendan ver el video 7 por que este es el video 8 del usuario(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0i2WulWScw0&list=PLkaQhEBG4ck0umP9RDTTn6scg-Xysaew1&index=6&t=375s)  J&G proyectos -->
      
           <h1>Registro Usuarios</h1>
       <table border="2" align="center"> 
               <tr>   
                  <td>Usuario:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" name="usuario" size=45 placeholder="Digite usuario"> </td>  <!--value es el valor por defecto esto con el fin de evitar de que en caso de error se tenga que volver a digitar todo, ya que se borra -->
              </tr>   
              <tr>  
                  <td>Contraseña:</td>
                <td> <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" placeholder="Digite contraseña" > </td>
               </tr> 
              
        <tr>
                   <td COLSPAN="2"> 
         <center>     
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ingresar" class="btn btn-success" name="btn1" id="btn1">  
             
               </center>
          </td> 
      </tr> 
       </table>
            <p></p>
                   <center> 
            <a href="usuarios.php">Registrar usuario</a> 
               </center> 
          
        <br></br>
         
    </body>
```

El error que me muestra es:

> Llamada al método indefinido Basededatos::prepare()

En la siguiente línea del archivo index.php:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=usuario AND contrasena=contrasena");
```

He visto las demás ayudas acerca del mismo error en stackOverflow, pero son muy distintas al presente inconveniente.

Muchas gracias por su colaboración.

Comment: como sugerencia primero leer la documentacion oficial de como usar la funcion https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: que hace distinta a tu pregunta; puedes justificarlo? desde mi punto de vista es igual ...

Comment: en el archivo index.php, hice lo siguiente:  $db= new Database();   $sqln='SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=? AND contrasena=?'; $query = $db->prepare($sqln,array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY)); $query->execute(array('usuario'=> $usuario,'contrasena'=> $contrasena));
     $usuario  = $query->fetchAll();  
     $contrasena = $query->fetchAll();                                                          
 pero desafortunadamente me muestra el mismo error.