# Error con la funcion Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php

Cordial saludo equipo quiero solicitarles su colaboración con el siguiente inconvenientes que se me presenta, agradezco su amable colaboración de antemano.

En otra ayuda sobre un inconveniente similar que se me presenta, me sugieren que arregle el error de la siguiente manera:

```
$db = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $contra, $bd);
```

Pero en mi caso, yo tengo: `$db = new Database();` y al realizar el proceso anteriormente descrito, me muestra los siguientes errores:

> Notice: Undefined variable: host in C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4s\index.php on
> line 26
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: db in C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4s\index.php on
> line 26
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user
> 'hecalitro'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in
> C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4s\index.php on line 26

Vale mencionar que mi aplicación no tiene contraseña para la base de datos y ella misma no tiene contraseña en Mysql WorkBench.                                                                      Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan prestar.

Comment: Creo que deberias agregar index.php, sobre todo alrededor de la linea 26.. no?

Comment: Sería bueno que añadas el Código de la class ```new Database``` y index como te mencionan, para ver como estas creando la variable ```$bd``` y ```$host```, luego en el mensaje dice que si tienes contraseña en tu *localhost* y que te deniega el acceso **Access denied for user 'hecalitro'@'localhost' (using password: YES)**, luego respecto al mensaje te está diciendo que dichas variables no están definidas, lo mejor iniciar dichas variables en ```null``` al principio de tu código, algo como ```$host = $bd = null;```

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta es derivada de [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/497561/54039), mucho mejor planteada. Te sugiero borrar esta y editar la anterior para agregar la información necesaria, si falla la conexión a la base de datos, entonces fallará también cualquier consulta.